# AWS HTTP API Gateway: stage variables

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am using the HTTP API gateway, and I cannot find anywhere to set stage variables. In all the guides I find, they reference setting stage variables, but those guides are all for the REST API protocol.

Is there a way to do this with the http API, and if so, how?

Comment: Are you trying to do this in the API Gateway console, or in a CloudFormation stack template?

Answer (score 0):

You can set stage variable in the **Edit Stage** page. This page can be accessed from the "Deploy > Stages" menu in the navigation pane on the right. Then, click "Edit" button to edit the stage. In the **Edit Stage** page, there is a panel to let you add/remove any stage variable.

[image]
[image]